# Web App. Vs. Desktop App (Java Swing App)

Tags: java, swing, web-applications

I want to develop an application where server pushes a lot of data to client. (20 kb every 20 milliseconds) 500kbps. All of the data are double/float values.

I am trying to answer the question, if there is something inherent to desktop apps (Java Swing app) which will make it a better option for this use case as compared to a web app where  data will be pushed over http.

Is there something about Java swing app and how data transfer takes place there from server to client, that makes them faster as compared to web apps (tomcat as app server .. JS at client side).

And how answer varies, if I say that web server and application are on the same local network.

Comment: Java Swing is a UI framework, and has nothing to do with how a client and server talk to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My vote is desktop, but I'm bias (when the only tool you have is a hammer...)

My first thought is threads and custom networking. You get the added benefit of push and pull protocols as you need (yeah you can get this in a web environment to, but Java was designed for this, AJAX has been bent this need)

I'd also push a diverse and customisable UI toolkit, but one might argue that you can achieve this using HTML, but I've, personally, found the Swing toolkit faster to get running & easier to maintain, IMHO.

The downside would have to the need to install the app on each client machine and deal with updating

That's my general opinion anyway, hope it helps

The other question is, what does the app need to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I will elaborate - All this data consist of some meter readings. Meters throw a new data every 20millisecond. Lets say there are 1000 of these meters, each meter reading tuple has 3 double values. Client app needs to plot these data points as required by user. But then there is a graphical representation of meters, where nodes(meters) are supposed to change color dynamically based on readings. So every moment, all the readings (Data) is required. I am using javascript at client side. The workaround for plotting- to render multiple points(10) every 200ms.

Comment: there is [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)

Comment: Rendering multiple points at a time saves over head of rendering every 20 milliseconds. Using server sent events (one way communication from server to client). Your replying is very helpful. So,I think your verdict is : with desktop app it is easier to accomplish such data volume and transfer rates (25kb per 20 millisecond) as compared to web apps. Please correct me if I am wrong. And please suggest how and why is that.

Comment: It's difficult to say for sure, what you do get is finer control (for example, you could dump the data to a local database for caching if the client wasn't able to keep up). You also get control over the rendering process, rather then being at the mercy of different webkits (you also get over cross browser issues). You gain custom component design and workflow. If done both desktop & web coding, prefer desktop for complex issues, personally, but then you come across something like stack overflow which has a well implemented Ajax design ;)

Comment: I'd put together a simple example of each a test its through put over an extended period of time, as that's where your going to find the issues

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unlikely that the UI will be displaying 1000 meters all at once.  The users will most likely be looking at small number of meters at a time.  The UI only needs to be updated for the meters that are displayed on the screen.  This should cut down on the load considerably. Assuming that networking and cache database components will be about the same for both web as well as desktop app, the real differentiator then becomes how fast the charts/graphs can be rendered, and how often or how many people will be inclined to use it.

MadProgrammer's suggestion of prototyping make sense. The test data gained from the prototypes would answer the performance question.

Web based will be more useful/valuable because it can be used from any desktop, tablet or smartphone. I am assuming that it is desirable to get the data in front of as many users as possible, anytime and anywhere. Also, I don't think human eye can detect 20ms updates. You could probably make that longer and users would not even notice it. Movies are about 25 frames a second, i.e. 40ms/frame.

How many concurrent user are you anticipating? I don't think that should affect the solution as both can be made scalable.

Comment: Thanks for such a nice response, Arun. Well not more than 100 concurrent user (that too is bloated) on any day. So accessibility, I guess is not a factor.  This favors desktop app over web ?   Another pointer is that though user won't be seeing all those 1000 real time plots at a go, there are other features that demands server to send all those readings to client all the time. Ex.-there is a node graph representing meters, where each node color changes depending on reading.

Comment: Yes, I won't be sending data every 20 ms, but clubbing them and sending every second or so in either case.  So, with these inputs does it helps decision making when it comes to (web app vs. swing app). I further will be doing contouring and other stuff, so not sure how easy and tough is to do all that in swing.